# xCode Archiving ipa with UITesting for AWS Device farm

Tags: ios, xcode, amazon-web-services, jenkins

I am doing for UITesting and I have tried Jenkins. I am planning to try AWS Device farm.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/test-types-ios-xctest-ui.html#test-types-ios-xctest-ui-prepare

It say like this.

> Before you upload iOS XCTest UI tests to Device Farm for testing, make
>   sure that your iOS XCTest UI test runner bundle is contained within a
>   properly formatted .ipa file. To create an .ipa file, you can place
>   your my-project-nameUITest-Runner.app bundle in an empty Payload
>   directory. Next, archive the Payload directory into a .zip file and
>   then change the file extension to .ipa. The *UITest-Runner.app bundle
>   is produced by Xcode when you build your project for testing, and it
>   can be found in the Products directory for your project.

I don't understand about that. How can I archive so that my UITesting is together with ipa file? I did like this (as shown in below image) and it is not okay to test on aws device farm.

[image]

**Edited**

I have tried with below method and I still got issue. I need to upload ipa file 2 times. What kind of ipa file I need to upload for 1st and 2nd time?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I work for the AWS Device Farm team.

@ThrowingSpoon is right in interpreting the archive part for the tests.

1. Device farm needs both your app and your tests in form of .ipa files. The app and the test will be two separate uploads. In the screenshot you posted you an see the 5 steps on the left side. The first upload will be your application ipa and the second upload be your test in step 2.
2. For your app this is a straight forward process through Xcode. Archive your app and find the ipa using show in finder.
3. In case of your tests, Xcode does not produce an ipa of your tests so we have to create one.
4. First build your project for testing.
5. The *UITest-Runner.app bundle will be produced by Xcode under the Products directory for your project.
6. Create an empty "Payload" (case sensitive) folder and add the *UITest-Runner.app under "Payload".
7. Right click on the Payload folder and Compress it to a zip file.
8. Rename the .zip file to .ipa (It may ask you if you want to keep the extension, accept it)
9. The .ipa formed is what you upload in step 2 of the screenshot that you posted.

Hope that clarifies your doubt.

Comment: I don't see *UITest-Runner.app after building for test.

Comment: How to prepare the application IPA file. Which certificate will I create the IPA file AppStore, AdHoc or Development profile? NikofTime

Comment: @NikofTime In Xcode 10 there is no way to find the ipa using Show in Finder. There is only the option to "Distribute App" with options "iOA App Store", "Ad Hoc", "Enterprise", and "Development". Which is the correct method of distribution. This is not present in AWS documentation.

Comment: I've gotten this to work with a "Development" deployment. When it is complete an "Export" button is displayed, which saves an ipa file that can be uploaded via Device Farm's UI.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a tutorial on how to prepare your tests to run on AWS Device Farm, please take a look for a step by step approach.
http://mobdesignapps.fr/blog/2016/9/17/running-your-test-on-aws-device-farm?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=answer&utm_term=37184633

The first file you need to upload is the application archive that you build by selecting Project > Archive. The second one is the IPA containing your tests. Which you'll find step on how to generate it in my blog post.

Short version is:

1. Select your test target and choose Project > Build For testing
2. The *UITest-Runner.app bundle will be produced by Xcode under the Products directory in your derived data folder.
3. Create an empty "Payload" (case sensitive) folder and add the *UITest-Runner.app
   under "Payload".
4. Right click on the Payload folder and Compress it to a zip file.
5. Rename the .zip file to .ipa

Answer (score 0):

When the instructions say *archive* I think it just means *compress*. 
[image]

The process should be:

1. Build your project for testing
2. Put the my-project-nameUITest-Runner.app bundle into an empty folder
3. Right click **on the new folder** and compress it to a zip
4. Rename the zip to an ipa (OSX will probably warn you that the file might get corrupted)

I feel like OSX used to say *archive* they must have changed it at some point.

Comment: Thanks. I still got issue. I have uploaded new photo in my question. I need to upload ipa file two times. What kind of files should I upload?

Comment: I'd check the directory layout inside the ipa is correct.